# RSpec testing non validating has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I have a many to many relationship between documents.

Say I have `document1` and `document2`. I have a many to many table where there are parents and children.

**document.rb**

```
  has_many :child_relationships, :class_name => "DocumentRelationship", :foreign_key => "child_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :parents, :through => :child_relationships, :source => :parent

  has_many :parent_relationships, :class_name => "DocumentRelationship", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :children, :through => :parent_relationships, :source => :child
```

**document_relationship.rb**

```
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Document", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => "Document", :foreign_key => "child_id"

  validates_uniqueness_of :child_id, :scope => [:parent_id]

  validates_presence_of :parent_id
  validates_presence_of :child_id
  validate :obeys_chronology

  def obeys_chronology
    errors.add(:child_id, "must be created after its parent") if child_id.to_i < parent_id.to_i
    errors.add(:child_id, "cannot be its own parent") if child_id.to_i == parent_id.to_i
  end
```

If I say `document2.children << document1` it appropriately fails validation, but I don't know how to write a test for this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to the collection

```
document2.children << document1
document2.children.contain?(document1).should == false
```

Then make sure it's not in there.

Comment: I just tried that.   
     Failure/Error: d2.children << d1
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Child must be created after its parent
     # ./spec/models/document_spec.rb:65:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'